# How do I fix Azure Websites to stop confusing .Net Framework 4.5 with 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to publish a simple Asp.Net MVC 4 project using Continuous Publishing in TFS online and I am getting the error:

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
Exception Message: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v4.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_APPPOOL_VERSION_MISMATCH. (type DeploymentDetailedException)

Comment: If I change the Framework in the Azure Websites to 3.5 to force another error look what it gives to me: Exception Message: The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v2.0'. This application requires 'v4.5'.

Comment: Which version of .NET do you have configured to be used for your site at [the management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com)?

Comment: It is .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: The problem is the TFS Online flow of publication. I published right from VS2012 publish tool for Azure and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I found my mistake: I didn't follow the script: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/ . The continuous deployment only works with the 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your project:

```
<IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>True</IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>
```